# how to retrive cookis from browser

Tags: cookies, jwt, backend, express-jwt

I have stored cookies in browser from backend.
Using these lines of code.

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  try {
    let token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    this.tokens = this.tokens.concat({ token: token });
    await this.save();
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

////////

```
const token = await loginNow.generateAuthToken();
        res.cookie("jwtoken", token, {
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 100000000000000),
          httpOnly: true,
        });
```

I don't have understanding how i can retrieve it in frontend so that i can verify the user i want get these from frontend.How i can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of your cookie, you use the example function below to get the value of it using JavaScript on the Front-end. (From W3Schools)

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible using cookies hook in ReactJS

Comment: Yes, you can use useState for each cookie you want to store. This site has something about it: https://medium.com/swlh/react-hooks-usecookie-hook-26ac06ff36b0